# How do I call the object in my script in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get this script set up programmatically through C#. That part is working fine.

```
    public static void ToolDatePicker_BS(ref StringBuilder Script, string Name)
    {
        Script.Append(@"<input type='text' name='");
        Script.Append(Name);
        Script.Append("'id='");
        Script.Append(Name);
        Script.Append(@"'value'/>");

        Script.Append(@"<script>");
        Script.Append(@" $(function() {");
        Script.Append(@"$( '#");
        Script.Append(Name);
        Script.Append(@"' ).datepicker({");
        Script.Append(@"showOn: 'button',");
        Script.Append(@"buttonImage: './calendarFull.png' ,");
        Script.Append(@"buttonImageOnly: true");
        Script.Append(@"});");
        Script.Append(@"});");
        Script.Append(@"</script>");
    }
```

Then after dynamically adding the script with the textbox object into the html, I need to call the textbox object to get and set text into it.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        MyDatePicker.ToolDatePicker_BS(ref sb, "StartDateTextBox");
        StartDateTextBoxPH.Text = sb.ToString();
        StartDateTextBoxText = StartDateTextBox.Text();//This is the area with the problem.
    }
```

Obviously since I defined the StartDateTextBox within quotes the compiler isn't gonna know it's a object now so I'm getting this error.

The name 'StartDateTextBox' does not exist in the current context

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem, can you elaborate on it?

Comment: Do you have `javascript` tagged simply because that is what you are trying to output/build, or is there some `javascript` related problem I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think StartDateTextBox.Text would be a property.

How about removing those brackets:

```
StartDateTextBoxText = StartDateTextBox.Text;
```